# Nuxt with Vuetify. CSS in HEAD tag

Tags: node.js, webpack, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I was installed [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) via command `npx create-nuxt-app` with [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/) plugin. Then I ran server via `npm run dev` or `npm run build && npm start` and in page source I see CSS styles of Vuetify in `<head>` tag. After some googleing I found advice add `extractCSS: true,` in build section of `nuxt.config.js`. After that when I run `npm run build && npm start` css files are generating and linking to pages, but I still see some CSS styling (~500 lines) in `<style data-n-head="true" id="vuetify-theme-stylesheet" type="text/css">`. How I can hide them to CSS file instead of displaying in `<head>` tag.

And how I can extract CSS when start `npm run dev` (pretty annoying to scroll this CSS when debug HTML layout)?

Comment: Best tip I have is not to scroll through CSS but to just use the Inspect tool in your browser, select an element and check what styles are currently applies to it. You can mess about with its styles there quick and easy and then bring stuff back over to your source files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly the same issue but I found had many lines of Vuetify colours CSS in the head of each pre-rendered html file. I eventually found https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/#variations.

> When Vuetify generates your application’s theme, it creates 9 variants for each color. For majority of users, these variants are rarely used. This is an opt in feature that will be false by default in the next major version.

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    options: { variations: false },
  },
})
```

Adding `options: { variations: false }` as above (along with `extractCSS: true` in Nuxt.config.js) got rid of all superfluous CSS in the pre-rendered html.